# Import CSV which every cell terminated by newline

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I have CSV file. The data looks like this :

```
PRICE_a
123
PRICE_b
500
PRICE_c
1000
PRICE_d
506
```

My XYZ Table is :

```
CREATE TABLE XYZ (
DESCRIPTION_1 VARCHAR2(25),
VALUE NUMBER
)
```

Do csv as above can be imported to the oracle?
How do I create a control.ctl file?

Comment: comma separated values (csv). What's in a name...

Comment: will be much easier if you can preprocess that file so each record is on 1 line, i.e. `Price_a,123` Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it without having to do any pre-processing.  Use the `CONCATENATE 2` clause to tell SQL-Loader to join every 2 lines together.  This builds logical records but you have no separator between the 2 fields.  No problem, but first understand how the data file is read and processed.  SQL-Loader will read the data file a record at a time, and try to map each field in order from left to right to the fields as listed in the control file.  See the control file below.  Since the concatenated record it read matches with TEMP from the control file, and TEMP does not match a column in the table, it will not try to insert it.  Instead, since it is defined as a `BOUNDFILLER`, that means don't try to do anything with it but save it for future use.  There are no more data file fields to try to match, but the control file next lists a field name that matches a column name, `DESCRIPTION_1`, so it will apply the expression and insert it.

The expression says to apply the regexp_substr function to the saved string `:TEMP` (which we know is the entire record from the file) and return the substring of that record consisting of zero or more non-numeric characters from the start of the string where followed by zero or more numeric characters until the end of the string, and insert that into the DESCRIPTION_1 column.

The same is then done for the VALUE column, only returning the numeric part at the end of the string, skipping the non-numeric at the beginning of the string.

```
load data
infile 'xyz.dat'
CONCATENATE 2
into table XYZ
truncate
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
  TEMP          BOUNDFILLER CHAR(30),
  DESCRIPTION_1 EXPRESSION  "REGEXP_SUBSTR(:TEMP, '^([^0-9]*)[0-9]*$', 1, 1, NULL, 1)",
  VALUE         EXPRESSION  "REGEXP_SUBSTR(:TEMP, '^[^0-9]*([0-9]*)$', 1, 1, NULL, 1)"
)
```

Bada-boom, bada-bing:

```
SQL> select *
   from XYZ
   /

DESCRIPTION_1                  VALUE
------------------------- ----------
PRICE_a                          123
PRICE_b                          500
PRICE_c                         1000
PRICE_d                          506

SQL>
```

Note that this is pretty dependent on the data following your example, and you should do some analysis of the data to make sure the regular expressions will work before putting this into production.  Some tweaking will be required if the descriptions could contain numbers. If you can get the data to be properly formatted with a separator in a true CSV format, that would be much better.

Comment: pluse-uno for `concatenate 2` ! Learned something! Thanks.